# How to convert video from avi to mkv via python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, avi, mkv

I am engaged in video processing and faced the problem of converting the avi format to mkv. I try to solve this problem,with  opencv library, but not one codec was able to record video in mkv format.
Example

```
  fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIB ')
  out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mkv', fourcc, 20.0, (frames[0].shape[1], frames[0].shape[0]))

  for frame in frames:
     out.write(frame)
  out.release()
enter code here
```

After that I found the library ffmpy it can convert from any format to any. I decided that I will save the result of my processing in avi format, and then convert to mkv using this code

```
def convertVideo():
ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(
    inputs={'output.avi': None},
    outputs={'output.mkv': None}
)
ff.run()
```

This fragment really converts avi to mkv, but if the avi file is created with opencv, then the conversion does not work.

How to write a file in mkv format on WindowsOS using opencv and python?

Can I convert a file received by opencv in avi format to mkv format using ffmpy?

Comment: Why do you write in `DIB` FOURCC format - it is inefficient, uncompressed and unpopular outside of Windows. Try writing in `MJPG`. You can probably put that directly in an `MKV` container too.

Comment: Yesterday I tried to do it and it wasn't help me but now you make my life better. You resolve my problem. Thank you very much

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with your project!